# Mod_ssl is missing in modules folder of Apache

Tags: apache, ssl, https, openssl, mod-ssl

I am trying to convert my PHP application from http tp https. I got all the SSL certificates loaded in my server. But when restarting apache server I found the error as :

> "Cannot load G:/APPS/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/modules/mod_ssl.so into server: The specified module could not be found".

I checked the modules folder and it seems there is no such module exists in my Apache installation. How do I download/install this module? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Shilpa

Comment: Greetings, please specify: 1) which system you are running this on (Windows / Linux / other) and the version and flavor (ex. which linux).  2) did you compile it yourself or is this a precompiled version you installed / downloaded?  The answer will differ greatly based on these details.

Comment: Hi Nic3500, I am working on windows server 2012 OS. The apache which i downloaded and installed is Apache 2.2 which is a precompiled version.

Comment: Since it is precompiled, it expects the module to be there.  So the package you downloaded is incomplete or was not compiled with ssl support.  I suggest 1) use Apache 2.4, drop 2.2.  2) try to find a forum or help page for the specific precompiled package you use.  3) or download another one (ex. one that has SSL enabled, or WAMP maybe?)

Comment: Hi Nic3500, thankyou for the suggestions. I have tried by adding the ssl module from same version of apache installation of my local machine. Then i restarted the server and it worked for me. May be it is not the correct solution but this workaround was useful for me. Thanks, Shilpa